# Groovy : Can I use assert in conjuction with elvis operator?

Tags: groovy

I would like to increment the values based on assert results :

```
def a = 1 
def b = 1
def c = 0
def d = 0

(assert a==b, "Mismatch") ? (c++) : (d++)
```

Is it possible?

Comment: if a!=b, assert throws.  when do you expect `(d++)` to happen?

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstood one important part - `assert` is not a function and it does not return any value. It is a Groovy's (and Java) keyword (statement) that throws an exception if the expression on the right side evaluates to `false`, but it does not return any result. However, you can achieve expected result using [ternary operator](http://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_ternary_operator) in the way it was designed to use:

```groovy
def a = 1
def b = 1
def c = 0
def d = 0

a == b ? (c++) : (d++)

println "c = ${c}, d = ${d}"
```

Output:

```
c = 1, d = 0
```

> You can read more about using assertions in Groovy's official ["Testing Guide, chapter 2.1 Power Assertions"](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/core-testing-guide.html#_power_assertions).

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to "ignore" the `assert` and continue, you can catch the exception it throws.  E.g.

```
 def a = 1
 def b = 1
 def c = 0
 def d = 0

 try {
    assert a==b, 'Mismatch'
    c++
 }
 catch (AssertionError e) {
    d++
 }

 println([a,b,c,d])
```

I'd only use tactics like that, if some foreign code dictates that on me.  This is very convoluted code unless you want to abuse the power-assert to generate a nice "warning" log message for you.